# SQLAlchemy Join Table with a field to order the rows

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

We are migrating from Grails to Python (and Flask). I would like to be able to use the current database structure from our Grails apps in SQLAlchemy.

In Grails I have some domain classes like this:

```
class Asset {
  static hasMany = [documents:AssetDocument]
  List<AssetDocument> documents = new ArrayList<AssetDocument>();    
...
}

class AssetDocument {
...
}
```

That will create some tables like this in Postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE asset
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
... etc
)

CREATE TABLE asset_document
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
    .... etc
    )
```

And finally

```
CREATE TABLE asset_asset_document
(
  asset_documents_id bigint,
  asset_document_id bigint,
  documents_idx integer,
  CONSTRAINT fk_4pqxhfusa9cevslboxbucsjdn FOREIGN KEY (asset_document_id)
      REFERENCES asset_document (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

The asset_asset_document table joins the Asset table to the Asset_
document table.

In Grails because I declared the relationship as a List there is an Extra field document_idx this is the Index in the array so for tables like this

asset

```
 +-----+---------+-------+
 | ID  | Version | etc.. |
 +-----+---------+-------+
 |   1 |       0 | ..... |
 |   2 |       0 | ..... |
 +-----+---------+-------+
```

asset_document

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| ID  | Version | etc.. |
+-----+---------+-------+
|   1 |       0 | ..... |
|   2 |       0 | ..... |
|   3 |       0 | ..... |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

asset_asset_document

```
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| asset_documents_id  | asset_document_id  | documents_idx  |
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|                   1 |                  1 |              0 |
|                  1  |                  2 |              1 |
|                   2 |                  3 |              0 |
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

With this example asset where id = 1 has two asset_documents with ids = 1,2
Where asset id = 2 there is one asset_document with id = 3

The documents_idx field is incremented based on the index in the Array of AssetDocuments.

How do I map this in SQLAlchemy so that if I add an AssetDocument to my Asset relationship the document_idx is updated also ?

For example if I added an AssetDocument to the Asset where id = 2

```
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| asset_documents_id  | asset_document_id  | documents_idx  |
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|                   1 |                  1 |              0 |
|                  1  |                  2 |              1 |
|                   2 |                  3 |              0 |
|                   2 |                  5 |              1 |
+---------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

So far I can see that I need to have

```
t_asset_asset_document = Table(
    'asset_asset_document', metadata,
    Column('asset_documents_id', BigInteger),
    Column('asset_document_id', ForeignKey(u'asset_document.id')),
    Column('documents_idx', Integer)
)

class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset'

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence('seq_asset'), primary_key=True)
    version = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    documents = relationship("AssetDocument",
                    secondary=t_asset_asset_document) #What needs to be here??

class AssetDocument(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset_document'

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence('seq_asset_document'), primary_key=True)
    version = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [Ordering List](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html) which handles such index updates automatically. However, it does not really work for many-to-many relationships. In order to work-around it, one can use [Association Proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) extension.

Full working code based on your model would be a below:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list

# ...

# :> convert relationship table to a mapped object
class AssetAssetDocument(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset_asset_document'

    asset_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'asset.id'), primary_key=True)
    asset_document_id = Column(ForeignKey(u'asset_document.id'), primary_key=True)
    documents_idx = Column(Integer)

    # :> define one-way relationship; will be used by association proxy
    document = relationship('AssetDocument')


class Asset(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset'

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence('seq_asset'), primary_key=True)
    version = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)

    # :> define a relationship to a mapped relationship object
    # this one is able to use `ordering_list` factory
    _documents = relationship(
        AssetAssetDocument,
        order_by='AssetAssetDocument.documents_idx',
        collection_class=ordering_list('documents_idx'),
    )

    # :> define a desired relationship
    documents = association_proxy(
        '_documents', 'document',
        creator=lambda _d: AssetAssetDocument(document=_d),
    )


class AssetDocument(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'asset_document'

    id = Column(BigInteger, Sequence('seq_asset_document'), primary_key=True)
    version = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
```

The usage is straightforward:

```
# INSERT TEST DATA
a1 = Asset(
    version=0,
    documents=[
        AssetDocument(version=1),
        AssetDocument(version=2),
    ])
session.add(a1)
session.commit()

# TEST MODIFICATIONS
# remove first one
del a1.documents[0]
# insert a position 0
a1.documents.insert(0, AssetDocument(version=3))
# add at the end
a1.documents.append(AssetDocument(version=4))
session.commit()


# check that the document_idx are properly ordered
q = (session
     .query(AssetAssetDocument.asset_document_id)
     .filter(AssetAssetDocument.asset_id == a1.id)
     .order_by(AssetAssetDocument.documents_idx)
     )
doc_ids = [x.asset_document_id for x in q]
assert doc_ids == [3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for this really good to understand solution!